# Next JS serial Api queries in getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js

I get Woocommerce product by ID and want to get related_products, but in the object returned only the ID of these product, i.e. to get the objects of these goods need to make new requests for each of the product ID, but as far as I know getServerSideProps works only once. I can pass it to a non-page component, but again I can't call getServerSideProps there. What to do in this case, who knows?

```
export default function ProductPage({product}) {
    ... //some code
    
    //get only ID's related products 
    <div className="slick-list">
        <div className="slick-track">
            {product.related_ids.map((item) => {
              return(
                  <ProductCard productData={item}/>
              )
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    const {data:product} = await getProductData(context.query.id)
    return{
        props: {
            product: product ?? {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getServerSideProps` only runs once per page request, but you can make multiple requests inside it. Is there any reason you can't make the subsequent requests after retrieving the required IDs?

Comment: but first I need to process the result of the first query to get the ID's. I.e. pass in {props} and that's is already render component .